# Prove that there exists no differentiable real function $g(x)$ such that $g(g(x))=-x^3+x+1$.

Tags: calculus

Prove that there exists no **differentiable** real function $g(x)$ such that $g(g(x))=-x^3+x+1$.

---

I have googled it but find nothing useful.

Now I know it's a [Iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#) problem.

It's an exercise problem after the chapter **DERIVATIVE**, so I guess maybe it's not too difficult.

Could you give me a hint to solve this problem?

Could you give me a **book list** about the  systematic introduction about Iterated function?

Comment: I am not aware of a solution, but if you are in a basic calculus course, it may want for you to apply the chain rule. There are reasons why every analytic function may look like a polynomial, that is Taylor's Theorem and Taylors' Series, but I am not sure about how one could extend this to all real functions without using analysis.

Comment: Note:  the problem does not specify that $g(x)$ is differentiable, nor even continuous.

Comment: @lulu maybe we can just assume it's third order differentiable or even higher order to get a solution at least?

Comment: I don't see any basis at all for assuming that the function is even continuous (unless the problem specified that).

Comment: @lulu Ooops, Sorry I forgot a condition..... $g(x)$ shall be differentiable.

Comment: That should help a lot. Please add that condition to your problem statement.

Comment: While we are at it: What are the allowed domains of $g$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter $(-\infty, +\infty)$.

Comment: Is there not a possible argument based on limiting behavior at $x \to \pm \infty$? Note that $g$ has to "send" $\{-\infty, +\infty\}$ into $\{-\infty, +\infty\}$, and none of the four possible maps gives the right limiting behavior $g \circ g(-\infty) = +\infty$, $g \circ g(+\infty) = -\infty$.

Comment: This would show more generally that there's no (continuous!) functional square root of any odd-degree polynomial with a negative leading coefficient.

Comment: I think the limiting argument works, and it's not hard to formalize it with the standard definition of limits at infinity.

Answer (score 9):

We have
$$
g(g(g(x)) = -g(x)^3 + g(x) + 1 \iff \\
g(-x^3+x+1) = -g(x)^3 + g(x) + 1
$$
For $x=1$ this turns into
$$
g(1) = -g(1)^3 + g(1) + 1 \iff \\
g(1)^3 = 1
$$
So $g(1) = 1$, if $g$ is a real valued function.

Differentiating both sides of $g(g(x)) = -x^3+x+1$ gives
$$
g'(g(x))\, g'(x) = -3x^2 + 1
$$
This gives
$$
g'(g(1))\,g'(1) = - 2 \iff \\
g'(1)^2 = -2
$$
which is not possible for real valued $g'(x)$ and thus for $g(x)$, as the derivative of a real valued function is a real valued function.

Comment: Clever! We had the same basic idea: prove that $1$ is a fixed point of $g$ and then use the chain rule.

Comment: I had the second part ready, before being able to nail $g(1)$.

Answer (score 6):

Recall that a *fixed point* of a function $f$ is a solution to $f(x) = x$.

The only fixed point of $g \circ g$ is $1$, so the only fixed point of $g$, if any, is also $1$, as any fixed point of $g$ is also a fixed point of $g \circ g$. If $g$ has no fixed point but instead interchanges $1$ and $\xi = g(1) \neq 1$, then the graph of $g$ must connect $(\xi, 1)$ and $(1, \xi)$. These points lie on opposite sides of the line $y=x$ regardless of the value of $\xi$, so $g$ has a fixed point not at $1$ by the Intermediate Value Theorem, a contradiction.

Therefore, $g$ has one fixed point, at $1$. Taking derivatives of $g \circ g$ gives $g'(x) g'(g(x)) = 1 - 3x^2$. Setting $x = g(x) = 1$ gives $g'(1)^2 = -2$, impossible. The conclusion follows.